# Split a string into smaller chunks of strings in apex

Tags: apex

I have a requirement where I need to split a string into a list of substrings with size 2 that is for example,

`String = 'ABCDEF J4'` and I want the output as

```
List<String> subStringList = {'AB', 'CD', 'EF','J4'}
```

I have tried it in javascript with the following :

```
var chunkStr = function(str, chunkLength) {
    return str.match(new RegExp('[\\s\\S]{1,' + +chunkLength + '}', 'g'));
}
```

I am not sure how to achieve the same in apex. Could someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The regex capabilities of Apex are documented in [Using Patterns and Matchers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want no whitespace in your result...

```apex
String s = 'ABCDEF J4';
s = s.deleteWhitespace();
List<String> subStringList = new List<String>();
for(Integer i=0; i<s.length(); i+=2) {
    subStringList.add(s.substring(i, i+2));
}
System.assertEquals(new List<String>{'AB', 'CD', 'EF', 'J4'}, subStringList);
```